# Output of using the same key in all 3 boxes of 3DES

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, 3des

I am trying to figure this one out: What would be the encrypted output for an input x if the same key K is used in all three boxes of 3DES?

The encryption scheme for 3DES with three different keys, and $k_3 = k_1$, is
$y=ek_3(ek_2(ek_1(x)))$. So, if the key is the same 3 times, then the encrypted output of x would be $y = k(k(k(x))) = ?$

Can someone let me know if what I have done here is correct?

Comment: Actually, we typically do 3DES in an "EDE" configuration; that is, the middle DES box runs in decrypt mode.  So, to encrypt, we would first DES encrypt with $k_1$, we then DES decrypt with $k_2$, and then DES encrypt with $k_3$.  My question to you: how would this change the answer?

Comment: [Why Triple DES used in EDE Mode](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1886/why-triple-des-used-in-ede-mode) [please have a look at this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/1889)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally, 3DES is configured in a mode called *EDE*, which means "Encrypt, Decrypt, Encrypt". This means that your encryption operation looks like this: $c = E(D(E(m, k_1), k_2), k_3)$. As it turns out, if all three subkeys are independent, the security of the system is not impacted by the second operation being a decryption.

The reason for this construction is a historic one. When 3DES was being introduced, people wanted a way to fall back to a "legacy" mode which amounted to just plain DES. This is handled through [keying modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options), of which there are three:

- Keying mode 1: All three subkeys are independent (which implies probabilistic inequality, though some implementations may enforce $k_1 \neq k_2 \neq k_3$ explicitly)
- Keying mode 2: $k_1$ and $k_2$ are independent, but $k_1 = k_3$.
- Keying mode 3: All three subkeys are equal, i.e.e $k_1 = k_2 = k_3$.

In keying mode 1, you get full 3DES with a 168-bit key (3 × 56-bit). In keying mode 2, you get a 112-bit version of 3DES (2 × 56-bit), though this keying mode is less commonly used in practice. In keying mode 3, the first two steps cancel out, leaving you with just DES:

$$\require{cancel}\cancel{a = E(m, k)}$$
$$\cancel{b = D(a, k)}$$
$$c = E(b, k)$$

Comment: I got the impression that the second mode is actually the most commonly used one..